How can I filter Bitbucket repositories by a specific topic or keyword?(with Python)
I’m trying to perform repository mining on Bitbucket and need to filter repositories by a specific topic or keyword. I know that the atlassian-python-api exists, but I haven’t been able to find a solution for filtering repositories by topic or keyword using this library.
Is there a way to achieve this with the atlassian-python-api or is there another Python library or method that would allow me to search for Bitbucket repositories by topics or keywords?

What do you want to filter?  The repo name? The code?

Yes, repo name, URL and username
